# Почему фонят колонки?

Tags: аудио

Я записал звук + сделал скрины эквалайзера. Есть скрин с шумодавом, но по пикам можно понять где косяк.

Запись тоже сделал само собой, только что-то не вижу, как её подгрузить сюда) Не нашёл в редакторе.

[image: С шумом от микрофона]

Comment: Запись загружай на диск/драйв

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13KZ0_WnbkpsiJK44oqfo8Uf1IK7bLg5x/view?usp=sharing